# How do I catch an exception throwing in an hardware interrupt?

Tags: c++

I'm working with an MCU in C++. 
I wonder what is the proper way to catch an exception throwing in an hardware interrupt, outside from this interrupt.

For example here :

```
    /* SPI callback */
    void cb(SPI_Type *base, spi_master_handle_t *handle, status_t status)
    {
        BaseType_t reschedule;
        if (status != kStatus_Success)
            throw std::runtime_error("SPI comm error");
        xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(rxtx_sem, &reschedule);
        portYIELD_FROM_ISR(reschedule);
    }
```

I would like the parent of the object to which this callback method belongs to be able to catch the exception. Is it possible?

Comment: You usually aren't allowed to throw C++ exceptions from interrupt handlers.

Comment: Be carefull that throwing in the callback may lead to not releasing properly HW resources (what about the call to `xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(rxtx_sem, &reschedule);` after the throw statement

Comment: Throwing C++ exceptions from hardware handlers rarely goes well.   You probably need to save the status information somewhere where the "parent of the object" can retrieve it.   How that retrieval would happen depends on how you've you've organised your objects, code, and any shared data.